# Moving crops within the same image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

Tried looking in the PIL module but couldn't find this covered.

I have an image, and I need to take a cropped piece of the image and move it to a different area within the same image. Simple enough, but I will need to do this for thousands of images,  so I will do batch image processing.

PIL seems too basic for this, any other libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PIL looks like it can do it very well, if you want to copy and paste rectangular areas.
Check the documentation on the crop and paste methods on image, on the documentation here:
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

If you need non-rectangular areas, though, you will have to resort to more sophisticated handling, but that does not preclude you from doing it with PIL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

[How to crop images with opencv in python](http://amiest-devblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-crop-images-with-opencv-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Python wrapper for the GD library](http://nets.ucar.edu/nets/intro/staff/mitchell/gd-ref.html) should do what you need:

```
copyTo(image[, (dx,dy)[, (sx,sy)[, (w,h)]]])
  copy from (sx,sy), width sw and height sh to destination image (dx,dy)
```